# Why does Firefox Return 'Server Not Found', and SeaMonkey Loads URL Perfectly?

Tags: networking, firefox

Firefox on my system can not connect to http://docs.jquery.com. When I try the same address in SeaMonkey, on the same system, it works perfectly.

Any thoughts why Firefox can not load the site?

Comment: Check that you don't have a proxy configured for firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime it happens,try the following

- Click on the Tools menu and select Clear Recent History.Or you can bring up the Clear Recent History window by pressing  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
- In the Time range to clear drop-down menu, select Everything
- Click the arrow next to Details to display the list of items to clear, then select the following items,

  ```
    o Cookies
    o Cache
  ```
- Then click **clear now**.
  [image]
- In your worst case if that din solve your problem then have a look at this troubleshooting **[link](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Basic%20Troubleshooting)**.

Answer (score 0):

Disable ipv6 in Firefox preferences.

- Type **about:config** in the address bar, press Enter.
- Find **network.dns.disableIPv6** in the list.
- Right-click -> Toggle.
- Restart Firefox and try again.